# Way to localize html files in android

Tags: android

Mine are html files which refer to images/CSS and JS files one folder up in the hierarchy.
Earlier I was using assets folder for storing these html/css/js and imaged but I came to know that these can't be localized from assets folder.

Now after moving these resources into the raw folder, there is a build error:

```
res\raw\jqueryui.css:0: Originally defined here.
res\raw\jqueryui.js:0: error: Resource entry jqueryui is already defined.
```

The raw folder contents are:

[image]

P.S. I had moved these contents from assets to raw folder and had clean/build my project
What do the above errors mean?

Comment: Because when you bring them to resources, the complier disregard file extension and build the "R.raw.jqueryui". unfortunately you have 2 file with same name is jqueryui. I suggest you change one file name to build success

Comment: Pls. post this as answer and I shall accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you bring them to resources, the complier disregard file extension and build the "R.raw.jqueryui". 
Unfortunately you have 2 file with same name is jqueryui. 
I suggest you change one file name to build success